# @nguniversal/express-engine not supported in Angular 8

Tags: angular

Angular CLI: 8.0.1
Node: 12.3.1
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 8.0.0

When run 
`ng add @nguniversal/express-engine --clientProject {{Project Name}}`

the the **@nguniversal/express-engine** package is added successfully, but not none of ssr files are created and I get the error:

> "Client app Project Name not found."

Answer (score 3):

please off the angular IVY form tsconfig.spec.json
"angularCompilerOptions": {
"enableIvy": false
}

and also form
tsconfig.app.json
"angularCompilerOptions": {
"enableIvy": false
}

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this same problem after I created an Angular 8 project and was getting the exact same

> "Client app Project Name not found."

After a little frustration I eventually realized what I was doing wrong. Embarrassingly I was executing the `ng add @nguniversal/express-engine --clientProject {projectName}` command at the wrong level. My terminal was pointing to the `src` directory, but I should have been executing in the directory containing the **package.json** file. SoOo if anyone else is running into this, be sure to run the command at the same level in your directory that the **package.json** folder is in!

Comment: Thanks, it helped and save some of my time. Already tried since 20 mins. I was using workspace feature in VSCode with Angular 8 and was having multiple applications. I was providing wrong path and sometimes running this command inside an application instead of running from the location where the 'common' package.json file is available, a couple of parent level. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 0):

There's no Angular 8 support yet from `@nguniversal/express-engine`. You should wait until the package is ready before using Angular 8.

This is the issue you can track until it is sorted.
https://github.com/angular/universal/issues/1176

Answer (score 0):

Since Angular CLI v6 we can simple

```
ng add @nguniversal/express-engine --clientProject <yourProjectName>
```